# Running .exe directly & through Shell VBA returning different results

Tags: vba, excel, ex

When I click directly in the .exe file "PrintUsers.exe", the output is correct.
But when I do that through VBA using Shell the result is different. It tries to find the text file in another directory. Why? See figure:

[image: figure]

SOLUTION: I am now using: GetModuleFileName(NULL, szEXEPath, 2048) instead of GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX);

Comment: Doesn't Look like the link went through.

Comment: what link? please add some explanation on what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: What does the Active Workbook Path return? If there are spaces in it, you might have some issues. If that is the case, surround the entire string on either side with Chr(34) which corresponds to "

Comment: Why do you keep editing the question to remove the image every time I edit it to display it?!?

Comment: Sorry, I was updating the image to make it clearer.

Comment: OK - I have edited the question once more to include the picture.  (Next time, you are on your own.)  I notice in the new image that the program is looking in a different location for the txt file than in the original image - how does the program determine which path to look in for the file?

Comment: I generated the .exe using C++. The folder is not specified so I understand it looks at the same folder of the calling file. It works when executing it directly by clicking or using command prompt. I do not understand why “shell” changes de behavior of the .exe file.

Comment: If you believe the program is meant to find the file in the directory where the program is located, rather than just looking in the current directory, then you will need to post the source code for that program so that we can help you fix it.  But, AFAIK, most languages require programs to do something special to look somewhere other than the current directory.

Comment: As a quick test to see whether your program (when not invoked from VBA) is looking in the current directory, or whether it is looking in the directory where the program is located, go to a command prompt and then enter `C:`, then enter `CD \ `, then enter `\Users\Douglas\University\Demo\PrintUsers.exe`, and see whether it works or not.  After that, enter `CD \Users\Douglas\University\Demo` and then enter `PrintUsers.exe` and see if that works.

Comment: The first test you suggested did not work BUT the second worked. What`s the difference? Thanks.

Comment: C++ code. Even using the full path the proble is still the same. ///                
                `char buff[FILENAME_MAX];  `
  `GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX);  ` 
  `char* folderAddress = buff; //"";  ` 
  `std::vector<std::string> vtext;  `
  `char * fileInstanceName = "\\doNotEdit.txt";  `
  `std::string fileInstanceName_str(fileInstanceName);   `
  `char buffer[256];  `
  `strcpy_s(buffer, folderAddress);  `
  `strcat_s(buffer, fileInstanceName);  `
  `char *filename = buffer;  `
  `std::ifstream ifile;  `
  `ifile.open(filename);  `

Comment: I don't know c++ but, judging by the name, the statement `GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX)` is getting the **current** directory (not the directory where the program is located), and you then concatenate that value with `doNotEdit.txt` to generate the filename to use. I don't know what the c++ code would be to obtain the program directory instead of the current directory so you have two choices ... (1) use the workaround in my answer to change the current directory to be the one where the program is, or (2) raise a new question asking how to change your c++ code to get the program directory.

Comment: It worked, thank you YowE3K. I am now using: `GetModuleFileName(NULL, szEXEPath, 2048)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I am now using: GetModuleFileName(NULL, szEXEPath, 2048) instead of GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX);

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `PrintUsers.exe` expects to find the file `doNotEdit.txt` in the current directory.

The best solution is to change that program to look for the file in the same directory as the program itself is located but, if that is not possible, get Excel to change the current directory before running the program, i.e. insert

```
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

prior to invoking `Shell`.

---

Also, as Yahya Hussein mentioned in a comment, spaces inside paths can cause issues.  There aren't any in your specific situation but, to ensure you don't have problems in future, consider using something like

```
myFile = """" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\PrintUsers.exe"""
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
Shell myFile, vbNormalFocus
```